# Server 2012R2 DHCP & DNS Updates

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, dhcp-server, dhcp-option

I have the following DNS settings configured on an DHCP scope:
[image: DHCP DNS Settings]

My question is, will the DNS entry be made against the DNS server that the DHCP is configured to go against or will it update the DNS server of the underlying client of the DHCP request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ability to register both A and PTR resource records enables a DHCP server to act as a proxy for clients running other operating systems.

DHCP requires the use of DNS dynamic update to keep name-to-address mapping information synchronized. **Using DHCP and DNS together on a network might cause problems** when using older, static DNS servers, which cannot interact dynamically when DHCP client configurations change.

Answer (score 1):

It will contact the DNS server configured on the DHCP server.